# Windows, git, batch file, command line: wont add new files

Tags: git

this is my batch file:

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
cd my/project/path
git add .
set /p msg=Commit message: %=%
git commit -am "%msg%"
git pull
git push
```

this is to auto commit+push my code. But when I checked, it turned out that it wont send new files

Comment: when I use the "git status", it says "nothing to commit"

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend not to do this (blindly commit and push all the changes), but if you wish, change `git add .` to `git add -A .` and `git commit -am "%msg%"` to `git commit -m "%msg%"`. This will commit everything: new files, changed files, file deletions.

Answer (score 1):

To do blindly commit and to push all the changes, you should create your .gitignore carefully to exclude files that should be be added to repository.

Another pointer for your batch files is that you'd better to do `git pull` before `git commit`. Before a commit, you need to check whether there is a conflict with other peoples' commit before hand.